# CDK VPC SubnetSelection from an imported subnet names

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-serverless

I'm working on defining a load balancer that is attached to a defined set of VPC subnets.
The list of VPC subnets to attach to is configurable in the code.
The VPC stack and appropriate subnets are pre-existing in the account, and the subnetIds are exported there as outputs (under "Foo" and "Bar" keys).

I'm importing VPC like this:

```js
        const vpc = Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'VpcName', {
            vpcName: vpcName,
        });
```

Defining LB like this:

```js
            const lb = new NetworkLoadBalancer(stack, 'LoadBalancer', {
    (...)
                vpcSubnets: getSubnets(vpc),
            });
```

getSubnets impl:

```js
        public getSubnets(vpc: IVpc): SubnetSelection {
            const nlbSubnetIds = [Fn.importValue("Foo"), Fn.importValue("Bar")];
            return vpc.selectSubnets(
                { subnetFilters: [SubnetFilter.byIds(nlbSubnetIds)] }
            );
}
```

This however doesn't work.

The list of subnets in the VPC is resolved to real subnets with real subnetIds - matching the ones in the account. However, the values from `nlbSubnetIds` are dummy placeholders like: `${Token[TOKEN.1293]}`.
This makes the output of `SubnetSelection` from `vpc.selectSubnets` empty.

How can I properly use the imported names to configure the subnets?

I tried to syntesize and deploy CDK but instead of desired result got the deployment error - list of subnets cannot be empty.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Use `Vpc.fromVpcAttributes` instead of `Vpc.fromLookup`

---

`Vpc.fromLookup`, a so-called [context method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html#context_methods), makes an initial cloud-side call to AWS at synth-time to retrieve and cache the deployed Vpc configuration from your account. Generally speaking [this is very convenient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2-readme.html#importing-an-existing-vpc). Not in your case, however. Your `Fn.importValue("Foo")` subnet IDs are [Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html) references at synth-time that get resolved only later, at deploy-time. As you discovered, this is too late for the filtering.

In contrast to the lookup method, [Vpc.fromVpcAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Vpc.html#static-fromwbrvpcwbrattributesscope-id-attrs) and similar `Something.fromSomethingAttribute` methods do not make cloud-side calls.  The method instead expects Vpc information to be provided as props.  The only info the returned `IVpc` [proxy object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_external) knows about the Vpc is what you tell it in the props.

```js
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, "Vpc", {
  vpcId: "my-vpc-id",
  availabilityZones: ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b"],
  publicSubnetIds: [Fn.importValue("Foo"), Fn.importValue("Bar")],
});
```

In your case, the consuming ELB construct only needs certain subnet ids, so it's not a problem that `vpc` isn't very well-informed:

```js
new elbv2.NetworkLoadBalancer(this, "NLB", {
  vpc,
  vpcSubnets: { subnets: vpc.publicSubnets },
});
```